# Google Cloud - App engine - Server to server tracking - Getting data into Bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, server-to-server

Ive recently started testing out using Google app engine in order to start server side tracking.
The test is being made with GA templates and GTM.
The server is up and running, the logs are say they should be, it seems to be working fine from what I can tell.

The issue i am facing is how do i access the data in the HTTP requests?
The logs show me info surrounding the requests but nots whats in it.

I have looked in the default bucket that was created but it is also empty.

I kinda get the feeling that my knowledge gap lies in: where is the data being stored and how do access it?

What i want is to find the data, confirm that it is the correct format and then forward it to BQ.

I have been reading about it extensively but I cant really find anything that matches what i want to do from start to finish or even the relevant parts.

But batch loading is something that Ive come across also streaming it to BQ.
This still doesnt really help since I havent figured out where the data is stored.